# Cache dependency

Tags: caching, architecture, redis

I start to implement cache for distributed system, my system is running in many separated services and several languages(C#, Java, AngularJS etc..).

After checking several solutions, I chose to implement the cache part with Redis.
During the design of cache solution I noticed that I have many cache dependency, the simplest way to solve this is to hold a table that manage all the dependencies(key -> multi-value of items that need to be deleted\updated on cache every time that key change). 
The question is if it's the right way to implement cache dependency?
I guess that in every software that use cache encounter the challenge of cache dependency, so I'm sure there's a better solution.

*Example of cache dependency - If the cache handle list of all users, and somebody delete or add a new user to the system, if the users are not updated on cache, then the system will display a wrong list of users.*

Thanks.

Comment: Cache is a trade-off between data consistency and performance. You **CANNOT** achieve both.

Comment: If you have a very read-heavy application you can afford a large write penalty and refresh all dependent caches every time a related object is updated. This sort of re-enforces @for_stack's point, as you are giving up performance for consistency, but only on write operation. For read operations you app would have both consistency and increased performance. This shows you can achieve both if you prioritize your use cases and make the tradeoffs elsewhere in your system.

Answer (score 3):

Cache invalidation is a super hard problem. However, there are many solutions. Keeping a collection (in Redis or elsewhere) of the cache objects and the associated domain objects that might be updated is a reasonable approach.

For complex interdependent caches there are many approaches, including Russian Doll Caching and [key-based caching](https://signalvnoise.com/posts/3113-how-key-based-cache-expiration-works).

The basic concept in key-based caching is to have a complex cache key that includes a fixed identifier and a dynamic one as well.

For example, if you have an object/fragment you want to cache called "user_navigation_bar" for User #123, you would write the cache to a key like `user_nav_bar:123:201705071122`. The last section is a timestamp when the user was updated. This is the dynamic part and will change every time your user does. To read the cache you only need the User ID and update timestamp. For the user list in your example you could use the most recent created/updated timestamp for all users, or have a UserList object that you update the timestamp on whenever a user is created/updated.

With this approach you never update or delete anything. All writes to the cache are to completely new keys.

You shouldn't be deleting cache items yourself. If you configure redis with a max memory size and an [LRU eviction policy](https://redis.io/topics/lru-cache) (Least Recently Used) it will automatically purge cache items that haven't been accessed the longest. As items like the "user_navigation_bar" get updated and written to new objects with new timestamps, the old ones will no longer be accessed and will eventually be purged.

If you are using redis for things besides cache objects you may want to run multiple instances. One configured as an LRU cache with a fixed max memory size and possibly no persistence. The other would be more like a default redis install, with no max memory and persistence for your permanent objects.

If you use a single instance of redis you can set a long-term expiration for your cache objects, and use the `volatile-lru` eviction policy so redis will only purge keys that have an expiration set. If you use this approach just make sure to set your max memory high enough so it has sufficient room for all of your permanent data.

Your question is extremely broad but hopefully this helps.

Comment: Nice thing you notice this question is broad. Next time please use the appropriate close reason, instead of writing an answer.